# How to replace dataframe values by other dataframe values, keeping values ​that are equal to both in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, toy1 and toy2. I would like to create a new dataframe, replacing the different values ​​that are in toy2 in toy1 and keeping the same values ​​(0) that are in toy1. Taking into account that there are different numbers of columns and rows.
So in this example below, **i want a result that is a dataframe of 208 columns and 2 rows.**

toy1:

```
structure(list(revenue = 0, risk = 0, target_amount = 0, company_years = 0, 
approved_commitee = 0, score = 0, reason_Capital_giro = 0, 
reason_Compra_equip = 0, reason_Compra_estoque = 0, reason_Cons_div = 0, 
reason_Expansao = 0, reason_Outros = 0, reason_working_capital = 0, 
serasa_0 = 0, serasa_1 = 0, serasa_1.5 = 0, serasa_1.8 = 0, 
serasa_2 = 0, serasa_2.6 = 0, serasa_3 = 0, serasa_3.1 = 0, 
serasa_3.2 = 0, serasa_3.3 = 0, serasa_3.4 = 0, serasa_3.6 = 0, 
serasa_3.8 = 0, serasa_4 = 0, serasa_4.2 = 0, serasa_4.4 = 0, 
serasa_4.6 = 0, serasa_5 = 0, pontualidade_0.75neg = 0, pontualidade_0 = 0, 
pontualidade_0.25 = 0, pontualidade_0.75 = 0, pontualidade_2.25 = 0, 
pontualidade_2.5 = 0, pontualidade_2.75 = 0, pontualidade_3 = 0, 
pontualidade_3.25 = 0, pontualidade_3.5 = 0, pontualidade_3.75 = 0, 
pontualidade_4 = 0, pontualidade_4.25 = 0, pontualidade_4.5 = 0, 
pontualidade_4.75 = 0, pontualidade_5 = 0, qualidade_divida_0 = 0, 
qualidade_divida_1 = 0, qualidade_divida_1.4 = 0, qualidade_divida_1.6 = 0, 
qualidade_divida_2 = 0, qualidade_divida_2.2 = 0, qualidade_divida_2.8 = 0, 
qualidade_divida_3.4 = 0, qualidade_divida_3.5 = 0, qualidade_divida_3.7 = 0, 
qualidade_divida_3.8 = 0, qualidade_divida_4 = 0, qualidade_divida_4.2 = 0, 
qualidade_divida_4.5 = 0, qualidade_divida_4.6 = 0, qualidade_divida_4.8 = 0, 
qualidade_divida_5 = 0, bancabilidade_0 = 0, bancabilidade_0.1 = 0, 
bancabilidade_0.2 = 0, bancabilidade_0.5 = 0, bancabilidade_0.6 = 0, 
bancabilidade_0.7 = 0, bancabilidade_0.8 = 0, bancabilidade_1 = 0, 
bancabilidade_1.2 = 0, bancabilidade_1.3 = 0, bancabilidade_1.4 = 0, 
bancabilidade_1.5 = 0, bancabilidade_1.6 = 0, bancabilidade_1.7 = 0, 
bancabilidade_1.8 = 0, bancabilidade_2 = 0, bancabilidade_2.1 = 0, 
bancabilidade_2.2 = 0, bancabilidade_2.3 = 0, bancabilidade_2.4 = 0, 
bancabilidade_2.5 = 0, bancabilidade_2.6 = 0, bancabilidade_2.7 = 0, 
bancabilidade_2.8 = 0, bancabilidade_3 = 0, bancabilidade_3.1 = 0, 
bancabilidade_3.2 = 0, bancabilidade_3.3 = 0, bancabilidade_3.4 = 0, 
bancabilidade_3.5 = 0, bancabilidade_3.6 = 0, bancabilidade_3.8 = 0, 
bancabilidade_3.9 = 0, bancabilidade_4 = 0, bancabilidade_4.1 = 0, 
bancabilidade_4.2 = 0, bancabilidade_4.4 = 0, bancabilidade_4.5 = 0, 
bancabilidade_4.6 = 0, bancabilidade_4.7 = 0, bancabilidade_4.8 = 0, 
bancabilidade_5 = 0, alavancagem_0 = 0, alavancagem_0.2 = 0, 
alavancagem_1 = 0, alavancagem_1.6 = 0, alavancagem_2 = 0, 
alavancagem_2.4 = 0, alavancagem_2.5 = 0, alavancagem_3 = 0, 
alavancagem_3.4 = 0, alavancagem_4 = 0, alavancagem_5 = 0, 
porte_0 = 0, porte_1 = 0, porte_1.4 = 0, porte_2 = 0, porte_2.4 = 0, 
porte_2.8 = 0, porte_3 = 0, porte_3.2 = 0, porte_3.6 = 0, 
porte_4 = 0, porte_4.4 = 0, porte_4.6 = 0, porte_4.8 = 0, 
porte_5 = 0, receita_recorrencias_0.6 = 0, receita_recorrencias_0.8 = 0, 
receita_recorrencias_1 = 0, receita_recorrencias_1.4 = 0, 
receita_recorrencias_2 = 0, receita_recorrencias_2.4 = 0, 
receita_recorrencias_2.6 = 0, receita_recorrencias_3 = 0, 
receita_recorrencias_3.2 = 0, receita_recorrencias_3.4 = 0, 
receita_recorrencias_3.8 = 0, receita_recorrencias_4 = 0, 
receita_recorrencias_4.4 = 0, receita_recorrencias_5 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_0 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_0.4 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_0.5 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_0.7 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_0.75 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_0.8 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_1 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_1.2 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_1.3 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_1.4 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_1.5 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_1.7 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_1.9 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_2.2 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_2.3 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_2.6 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_3 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_3.2 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_3.5 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_3.6 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_4 = 0, respaldo_patrimonio_4.4 = 0, 
respaldo_patrimonio_5 = 0, reputacional_1 = 0, reputacional_2 = 0, 
reputacional_2.5 = 0, reputacional_3 = 0, reputacional_3.5 = 0, 
reputacional_3.65 = 0, reputacional_4 = 0, reputacional_5 = 0, 
impacto_covid_1 = 0, impacto_covid_1.5 = 0, impacto_covid_2 = 0, 
impacto_covid_2.5 = 0, impacto_covid_3 = 0, impacto_covid_3.5 = 0, 
impacto_covid_3.65 = 0, impacto_covid_4 = 0, impacto_covid_5 = 0, 
business_sector_Comercio = 0, business_sector_Industria = 0, 
business_sector_Servicos = 0, state_AC = 0, state_AM = 0, 
state_BA = 0, state_CE = 0, state_DF = 0, state_GO = 0, state_MG = 0, 
state_MS = 0, state_MT = 0, state_PA = 0, state_PB = 0, state_PE = 0, 
state_PR = 0, state_RJ = 0, state_RS = 0, state_SC = 0, state_SP = 0, 
state_TO = 0, decision_motor_approved = 0, decision_motor_denied = 0), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

toy2

```
 structure(list(revenue = c(4397487.34, 198019.75), risk = c(12137650.06, 
469506.24), target_amount = c(150000, 1e+05), company_years = c(18, 
9), approved_commitee = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("NO", 
"YES"), class = "factor"), score = c(134, 128), reason_Compra_equip = c(1, 
1), serasa_1.8 = c(1, 1), pontualidade_0.25 = c(1, 1), qualidade_divida_1 = c(1, 
1), bancabilidade_0.2 = c(1, 1), alavancagem_1.6 = c(1L, 1L), 
    porte_4.6 = c(1, 1), receita_recorrencias_3 = c(1, 1), respaldo_patrimonio_0.5 = c(1, 
    1), reputacional_5 = c(1, 1), impacto_covid_3 = c(1, 1), 
    business_sector_Comercio = c(1, 1), state_GO = c(1, 1)), row.names = c(10L, 
12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: For the variables that are not in `toy2`, you have a single 0 while if they are in `toy2`, you have 2 values associated with it. Then how can you have 2 columns in the final dataframe?

Comment: I misspelled and edited, the final dataframe should be 2 rows, not 2 columns.
I think the code should check column by column on toy1 and compare with toy2. If the value is the same, keep the value of toy1, otherwise, keep the value of toy2. Row by row, then having a final dataframe with the number of lines equal to toy2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this :

```
a <- which(names(toy1) %in% names(toy2))
toy1[2,] <- 0
toy1[a] <- toy2
```

`toy1` has only 1 row while `toy2` has two. So I added an extra 0 row in `toy1`.

Comment: Wow, that was beautiful! Thank you very much!

Comment: Your method has the advantage that the ordering of the columns is preserved. My method has the advantage ( which I think  was implied in the Subject request)  that non-zero items in the non-`toy2` named columns would be carried forward into the next row.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is a `cbind.data.frame` method, you could `cbind` the portion of `toy1` that has non-matching column names to all of `toy2`. R does recycling of needed rows in this situation. Admittedly the column order might not be the same. It could be restored to the original ordering if needed.

```
toy1.2 <-cbind(toy1[ ! names(toy1) %in% names(toy2) ], toy2 )
toy1.2
#---------------------------

  reason_Capital_giro reason_Compra_estoque reason_Cons_div reason_Expansao reason_Outros reason_working_capital
1                   0                     0               0               0             0                      0
2                   0                     0               0               0             0                      0
  serasa_0 serasa_1 serasa_1.5 serasa_2 serasa_2.6 serasa_3 serasa_3.1 serasa_3.2 serasa_3.3 serasa_3.4 serasa_3.6
1        0        0          0        0          0        0          0          0          0          0          0
2        0        0          0        0          0        0          0          0          0          0          0
#snipped a bunch of rows, leaving the new data from toy2

    revenue       risk target_amount company_years approved_commitee score reason_Compra_equip serasa_1.8
1 4397487.3 12137650.1        150000            18               YES   134                   1          1
2  198019.8   469506.2        100000             9               YES   128                   1          1
  pontualidade_0.25 qualidade_divida_1 bancabilidade_0.2 alavancagem_1.6 porte_4.6 receita_recorrencias_3
1                 1                  1                 1               1         1                      1
2                 1                  1                 1               1         1                      1
  respaldo_patrimonio_0.5 reputacional_5 impacto_covid_3 business_sector_Comercio state_GO
1                       1              1               1                        1        1
2                       1              1               1                        1        1
```

Comment: This also solved my problem, really the columns were in another order, but maybe it's easier to use in a function, thanks!